# What is best way to add required mark with label decorator - Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

i have a question about using Zend_Form_Decorator_Label,in order to get following result when form element is required i need to get  Label-text * and i'm wondering how to achive that in most reusable way?

Is it to write new decorator or to override zend_View_helper_FormLabel ?
Maybe there are other ways to achive that?

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add one of the following options when you create decorator:

- **optionalPrefix**: a prefix to the label to use when the element is optional
- **optionalSuffix**: a suffix to the label to use when the element is optional
- **requiredPrefix**: a prefix to the label to use when the element is required
- **requiredSuffix**: a suffix to the label to use when the element is required

Code example:

```
$elementDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array('Label', array('requiredSuffix' => ' *')),
);

$userName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('userName');
$userName->setDecorators($elementDecorators);
$userName->setLabel('User Name');
```

Or alternatively you can explicitly set suffix/prefix on existing decorator:

```
$userName->getDecorator('Label')->setReqSuffix(' *');
$userName->getDecorator('Label')->setOptSuffix('(Optional) ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the Label decorator adds the CSS class `required` to the `<label>` element attached to a form input element specified as required, I have been able to add a symbol (like an asterisk) by using the CSS `:after` selector with a `content()` declaration:

```
label.required:after {
    content: "*";
}
```

But, I find it can be tricky to get the spacing right, to get the asterisk to render in bold or in the color I want, etc. As a result, I often just fall back to using CSS to render the label itself in bold or in a different color, and then add a legend ("Bold/Red fields are required" or some such) at the top or bottom of the form (often by creating my own custom legend decorator, but sometimes in the view-script itself).

Answer (score 3):

```
class FormDecorators {
    public static $simpleElementDecorators = array(
        array('ViewHelper'),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'requiredPrefix' => '<span class="required">* </span>')),
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'desc-item')),
        array('Errors', array('class' => 'errors')),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-item'))
    );
    }
```

And for element you use

```
 $elem->setDecorators(FormDecorators::$simpleElementDecorators)
```

I've added required prefix with 'requiredPrefix' param in label array.

```
array('Label', array('tag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'requiredPrefix' => '<span class="required">* </span>')),
```